# component status is not updated vue-js

Tags: vue.js

im new in vuejs, i have a component which is a custom table that receives a props,this is an array with all the data  in order that table consume and show the data. The main problem is that i got the logic to sort the field in the asc/desc table therefore when i click in one of the header the table invoke the next method

```
order(columnIndex: number) {
      const thisRef = this
      const arr = this.currentOrder;
      let sortedArray = this.rows
        .map((row, rowNumber) => ({
          row: row,
          rowNumber: rowNumber
        }))
        .sort((a, b): number => {
          const cellNumberA =
            thisRef.subcolumnsLabels.length * a.rowNumber + columnIndex
          const cellNumberB =
            thisRef.subcolumnsLabels.length * b.rowNumber + columnIndex
          const cellValueA = thisRef.getCellValue(cellNumberA)
          const cellValueB = thisRef.getCellValue(cellNumberB)
          return cellValueA - cellValueB
          if(arr[columnIndex]){
               arr[columnIndex] = false;
               return cellValueB - cellValueA
             }else{
               arr[columnIndex] = true;
             }
        }).map((rowWithRowNumber) => rowWithRowNumber.row)
      this.$store.dispatch('market/setSiData',sortedArray)
    },
```

This method receives one columnIndex this is the number of column in which has been click, the same one is worth for ask the position of the array and check if is true or false.

```
data() {
    return {
      columsOrder: [false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
    }
  },
```

The problem is a few times  this works, change for true and sometimes no, i have no idea why that is happen. Any  thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Change Detection Caveats - For Arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays):

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

You are doing (1) here:

```js
arr[columnIndex] = false
```

You should use [`this.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) instead:

```js
this.$set(arr, columnIndex, false)
```

Comment: I get the same result ..
sometimes updates and sometimes not